# non www page is redirecting to home page instead of that page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress website.But when I hit the url of indiavidual page without www it redirects to homepage instead of that page. All I want to fix it so that it redirects to that page only.

My website is : http://www.searzilla.co.uk/

PROBLEM: If I hit searzilla.co.uk/design/ ,it redirects to home page instead of design page.

Can anyone has any solution for this?

my htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: That's a standard .htaccess file...it sounds like the issue exists in your Apache config.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
# Redirect to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```